# Bcnf lossless join

Tags: bcnf

Are all relations in bcnf provide lossless join or can any relation be bcnf but not lossless join at the same tiem?

Is there a way to show that a relation that is not in bcnf but NOT lossless join.

Answer (score 0):

There are schemas in which no decomposition to 3.5NF is dependency-preserving.  See [(Tsou 1982)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/990511.990513) for an example.